# installing Solr PHP on VPS

Tags: php, solr, vps

im trying to install solr php extension on my VPS hosting server through the WHM cpanel but it getting me that error:

```
downloading solr-2.4.0.tgz ...
Starting to download solr-2.4.0.tgz (256,316 bytes)
.....................................................done: 256,316 bytes
64 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
Enable Solr Debugging (Compiles solr in debug mode) [no] : libcURL install         prefix [/usr] : libxml2 install prefix [/usr] : building in /opt/cpanel/ea-        php56/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/pear-build-rootalFRv4/solr-2.4.0
running: /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/solr/configure --    with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php-config --enable-solr-    debug=no --with-curl=/usr --with-libxml-dir=/usr
```

...

```
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to     regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for cURL support... yes, shared
checking for cURL in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the libcurl distribution -
easy.h should be in /include/curl/
ERROR: `/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/var/tmp/php-pear/solr/configure --    with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php-config --enable-solr-        debug=no --with-curl=/usr --with-libxml-dir=/usr' failed
```

is there any other way to install it?

Comment: You'll have to have libcurl installed first. I'm not familiar with WHM cpanel, but if you can ssh to the server or run commands / install packages directly in cpanel, it's usually located in libcurl-dev / libcurl-devel / curl-devel.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure whether libcurl is installed or not by issuing following command.

```
yum list|grep curl
```

If libcurl does not get populated in the list, you'll need to install it as below.

```
yum install curl curl-devel
```

Once cURL is installed, it will be installed in /usr/bin/curl.

Try installing Solr PHP again.

Comment: i think this is the last thing: how do i edit php.ini?
Installing '/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/solr.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/solr-2.4.0
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=solr.so" to php.ini